NSwag typescript-angular problem with enum prop names and DateTIme type
I have a problem with generating enums and DateTime attributes using Nswag and OpenApi.
The first problem is generating Enums, I would like them to have the following format:
export enum BillboardType {
    BB = 0,
    BB18 = 1,
    Direction = 2,
    Banner = 3
}

However, the open api cli generates it this way:
export enum BillboardType {
    NUMBER_0 = 0,
    NUMBER_1 = 1,
    NUMBER_2 = 2,
    NUMBER_3
}

My second problem is how DateFormat attributes are generated. Tsie creates a class where the given attributes are of the string type and I would like them to be of the Date type.
export interface BillboardBasicInformationDto { 
    city?: string | null;
    shopId?: number;
    zipCode?: string | null;
    province?: string | null;
    street?: string | null;
    streetNumber?: string | null;
    inventoryNumber?: string | null;
    billboardType?: BillboardType;
    billboardSubType?: BillboardSubType;
    billboardStatus?: Status;
    billboardStatusDateFrom?: string;
    billboardStatusDateTo?: string | null;
    width?: number;
    height?: number;
    billboardOwnerId?: number;
    mapUrl?: string | null;
}

public class BillboardBasicInformationDto
{
    public string? City { get; set; }
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public string? ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string? Province { get; set; }
    public string? Street { get; set; }
    public string? StreetNumber { get; set; }
    public string? InventoryNumber { get; set; }
    public BillboardType BillboardType { get; set; }
    public BillboardSubType BillboardSubType { get; set; }
    public Status BillboardStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTime BillboardStatusDateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BillboardStatusDateTo { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int BillboardOwnerId { get; set; }
    public string? MapUrl { get; set; }

    private class Mapping : Profile
    {
        public Mapping()
        {
            CreateMap<BillboardBasicInformationDto, Billboard>();
        }
    }
}

My config.nswag
{
  "runtime": "Net80",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
    "aspNetCoreToOpenApi": {
      "project": "Web.csproj",
      "msBuildProjectExtensionsPath": null,
      "configuration": null,
      "runtime": null,
      "targetFramework": null,
      "noBuild": true,
      "msBuildOutputPath": null,
      "verbose": false,
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "requireParametersWithoutDefault": true,
      "apiGroupNames": null,
      "defaultPropertyNameHandling": "CamelCase",
      "defaultReferenceTypeNullHandling": "Null",
      "defaultDictionaryValueReferenceTypeNullHandling": "NotNull",
      "defaultResponseReferenceTypeNullHandling": "NotNull",
      "generateOriginalParameterNames": true,
      "defaultEnumHandling": "Integer",
      "flattenInheritanceHierarchy": false,
      "generateKnownTypes": true,
      "generateEnumMappingDescription": false,
      "generateXmlObjects": false,
      "generateAbstractProperties": false,
      "generateAbstractSchemas": true,
      "ignoreObsoleteProperties": false,
      "allowReferencesWithProperties": false,
      "useXmlDocumentation": true,
      "resolveExternalXmlDocumentation": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceBasePath": null,
      "serviceSchemes": [],
      "infoTitle": "ExternalAd API",
      "infoDescription": null,
      "infoVersion": "1.0.0",
      "documentTemplate": null,
      "documentProcessorTypes": [],
      "operationProcessorTypes": [],
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "schemaNameGeneratorType": null,
      "contractResolverType": null,
      "serializerSettingsType": null,
      "useDocumentProvider": true,
      "documentName": "v1",
      "aspNetCoreEnvironment": null,
      "createWebHostBuilderMethod": null,
      "startupType": null,
      "allowNullableBodyParameters": true,
      "useHttpAttributeNameAsOperationId": false,
      "output": "wwwroot/api/specification.json",
      "outputType": "OpenApi3",
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto",
      "assemblyPaths": [],
      "assemblyConfig": null,
      "referencePaths": [],
      "useNuGetCache": false
    }
  }
}


And AddOpenApiDocument configuration:
services.AddOpenApiDocument((configure, sp) =>
{
    configure.Title = "ExternalAd API";

    // Add JWT
    configure.AddSecurity("JWT", Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
        Description = "Type into the textbox: Bearer {your JWT token}."
    });

    configure.OperationProcessors.Add(new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("JWT"));
});

Thank you in advance for your help and sorry for any mistakes.
I tried many methods, but the only thing I managed to get was an enum with string values, but I don't want this format.

For your enum issue, I implemented a custom XEnumNameSchemaFilter based on this repo. You can either use the package or use only the code you need.
Unfortunately atm I can't help you for the dates as you are using aspNetCoreToOpenApi. Personnaly, for a .NET + Angular app, I use openApiToTypeScriptClient (the .js file is generated based on my swagger.json api definition) and there we have dateTimeType attribute that solve the Date type issue in TS. I don't know if you could use the same thing here. I will look if I find something for the dates in your case. If someone has the answer, feel free to comment so I can add your solution to this answer.
